# Oracle 11g - SQL replace trash values

Tags: sql, regex, string, oracle, replace

I'm having major difficulty to do something which should be pretty simple.
I have column which have some data like this:
1,2,3,4,5,6

This numbers needs to be changed into descriptions so I'm using a nested replace functions in update:

```
UPDATE some_table
        SET some_column = REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(column_name,
            '0', ''),
            '1', 'some_desc_1'),
            '2', 'some_desc_2'),
            '3', 'some_desc_3')
        WHERE ID = some_id;
```

Everything would be great but when there are more numbers to replace (7,8,9 and so on) things start to get weird and I got duplicated results, some trash values (like number 0 somewhere between).

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The statement looks correct.  We'll need to see a reproducible test case to know what's really going on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that this is a delimiter problem.  So, `10` gets replaced as `1` and `0`.  The easiest fix is to put things in the right order.  Put the largest numbers first and go down to the smallest numbers:

```
replace(replace( . . . replace(col, '10', 'foo'), '9', 'bar) . . .)
```

Another problem may be that the descriptions contain numbers.  If that is the case, I would suggest that you modify the descriptions.

Comment: That's exactly what was the problem and I figure it out too when was writting an example. Thanks!